# Missing-asset-registry-path for @react-navigation/elements/lib/commonjs/assets/back-icon-mask.png on RN 70.6

Tags: android, react-native

```
When building my app I get the following error message since I switched to React Native 70.6 (Android and iOS), without @react-navigation everything works. On React Native 69.7, the app runs without problems with the identical @react-navigation versions.

Error: Unable to resolve module missing-asset-registry-path from /node_modules/@react-navigation/elements/lib/commonjs/assets/back-icon-mask.png: missing-asset-registry-path could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
> 1 | �PNG
  2 | 
  3 | 
  4 | IHDR2���gAMA��
                    �a cHRMz&�����u0�`:�p��Q<bKGD���̿tIME�
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:178:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:264:43)
    at Object.resolve (/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:170:21)
    at resolveDependencies (/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/graphOperations.js:466:33)
    at processModule (/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/graphOperations.js:232:31)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async addDependency (/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/graphOperations.js:361:18)
    at async Promise.all (index 18)
    at async processModule (/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/graphOperations.js:279:3)
    at async addDependency (/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/graphOperations.js:361:18)
```

Comment: ever resolved this one?

Comment: I have leave that project and create a new one

Comment: yep did the same.

Comment: i think the problem is with metro-server. when i run commad npx react-native start and the press a to build the app form metro server it give me the above error. if i run it wih normal command npx react-native run-android/run-ios the sometimes it is fine.